# Not getting json array in php

Tags: php, json

I am passing a json in my ajax request but it is just returning 10 every time, why??

whay my array in not getting passed??

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#list-3 .ajaxcall').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : { 
                    gpl_args : JSON.stringify({"cat":"26","posts_per_page":"4","paged":1}),
                    gpl_layout : {"show_thumb":"1","columns":"4","thumb_height":"85","thumb_width":"85","title_link":"1","content_excerpt":"50","posts_per_page":"4"}
            },
            success : function(response) {
                // The server has finished executing PHP and has returned something,
                // so display it!
                $("#list-3").append(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and:

```
$args       = isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args']);
//$args         = json_encode(isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args']));
print_r($args)
```

Update:

```
my data inside ajax:
   data    : { gpl_args : JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($args); ?>),
              JSON.stringify(gpl_layout   : <?php echo json_encode($layout); ?>)},
```

Comment: Well, you're not returning valid JSON

Comment: please tell me how to return valid JSON

Comment: $args is a boolean here, not an array.
try `die(json_encode(array('args'=>$args)));`

Comment: @UnLoCo please tell me why you are using die() ??

Comment: I am sending array not boolen: check this in my code `{"cat":"26","posts_per_page":"4","paged":1}`

Comment: I use `die` to make sure that the script exits immediately and output only the JSON encoded text and that to make sure I have a valid JSON.

Comment: OK, thanks for telling. but I am already passing an `json_encode($array)`

Comment: No, you are using `isset` which returns a Boolean.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: `echo json_encode($_REQUEST['gpl_args'])` would do, but the `die()` would work & halt the code there.

Comment: you can't `json_encode` json_encoded data... you have to `json_decode` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix.  You have to DE-code the json, not EN-code it.

```
$args = isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args']) ? $_REQUEST['gpl_args'] : null;
$args = json_decode(stripslashes($args));
print_r($args)
```

Comment: but now I am geeting `0` as a return. I am updating my question with rest of my php code.

Comment: getting the results now if i dont use json_decode, like this: `{\"cat\":\"26\",\"posts_per_page\":\"4\",\"paged\":1}0`

Comment: I see... we can fix that by unescaping first  I added `stripslashes()` to my example above.

Comment: man you are great, it solved my problem. Do i need to use `die()` or `exit()` at last??

Comment: No need to die or exit.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**See your php script:**

```
$args       = isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args']);
//$args     = json_encode(isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args'])); 
// $args is false（Boolean type）, But not json
print_r($args);  // print_r(false);  is show nothing!!
```

**right way:**

```
$json_array[] = isset($_REQUEST['gpl_args']) ? $_REQUEST['gpl_args'] : false;
echo json_encode($json_array);  // will show json string
```

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you printing the boolean result of isset() instead of the actual args?

Comment: You should post this as a comment, not as an answer.